# Java tile puzzle - how to place each separate piece in the correct location?

Tags: java, for-loop, puzzle

I am new to programming and in the process of working my way through a Java book and I am trying to learn about `Swing` and how to create simple `GUI`s etc.

I am trying to create a puzzle game that holds 9 tiles which are pieces of a puzzle. I have created a buffered image from which i am using the `getSubImage` method but i cannot figure out how to place each tile in the correct position, I know it should be a simple task but i just keep on creating the sub image in the same position - I am not sure how to move each piece into the correct location. I understand this is simple logic and i should know this!

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     {
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
       {
         BufferedImage b= bimg.getSubimage(j * w, i * h, w, h);     
         g.drawImage(b,0,0,w,h,this);   //0,0 are the problem                                                        
       }   
    }
```

Comment: Use the `i` and `j` variables to offset from 0 perhaps?

Comment: HINT: You have to use `i` and `j` along with your `h` and `w` to determine the place where you have to draw the next piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already had it partially down when you set the image:

```
BufferedImage b= bimg.getSubimage(j * w, i * h, w, h);
```

I'm referring to **j*w** and **i*h**

So why not draw them in the correct spot as well?

**Changing:**

```
g.drawImage(b,0,0,w,h,this);
```

**Into:**

```
g.drawImage(b, j*w , i*h ,w,h,this);
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much i really appreciate it! So easy when i think of it now.